# How to prevent cancelling Futures in nested `select!` macros?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am trying to make a struct in Rust using `tokio::select!` which allows me to send and receive message from different parties.

```rust
pub Destination {
    Alice,
    Bob
}

struct ConnectionsManager {
    rx_from_alice: UnboundedReceiver<Message>,
    tx_to_alice:  UnboundedSender<Message>,
    rx_from_bob: UnboundedReceiver<Message>,
    tx_to_bob:  UnboundedSender<Message>,
}
impl ConnectionsManager  {
    async fn listen(&mut self) -> Result<Message, anyhow::Error> {
        select! {
            received_message = self.rx_from_alice.next() => {
                return self.process_received_message(received_message).await
            }
            received_message = self.rx_from_bob.next() => {
                return self.process_received_message(received_message).await
            }
        }
    }

    async fn send(&mut self, message: Message, dest: Destination) -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
        match message {
            Destination::Alice => self.tx_to_alice.send(message).await,
            Destination::Bob => self.tx_to_bob.send(message).await,
        }
    }
   async fn process_received_message(&mut self, received_message: Option<Message>) ->  Result<Message, anyhow::Error>  {
      // Some further processing of the message
   }
}
```

The `Stream` implementation of `mpsc` channels guarantees that there will be no lost messages,so it looks fine so far.
The problem is I need to also use a `select!` in the code that calls the `ConnectionsManager::listen()`:

```rust
   async fn listen_to_a_lot_of_stuff(&mut self) ->  Result<Message, anyhow::Error>  {
       let conections_manager = ConnectionsManager::new(/* setting up...*/);
       loop {
          select! {
              processed_message = self.connections_manager.listen() => {
                  // .......
              }
              some_other_result = some_other_future => {
                  // .......
              }
          }
       }
   }
```

In that case, when `some_other_future` resolves while `ConnectionsManager::listen()` already received message from a channel and calls ConectionsManager::process_received_message()` on it, the message may be lost due to cancelling of the future.
Is there any pattern that allows to not lose any message in that case?

Some ideas that have failed so far:

- Saving `connections_manager.listen()` future or making it a `task` does not work, because I need to use `ConnectionsManager` tx channels while it is not awaited by `select!`. Storing the `listen()` Future makes calling `ConnectionsManager::send()` not possible in that case.
- Giving TX channels to Bob and Alice, and have just one RX channel in `ConnectionsManager` could work, but `ConnectionsManager` struct needs to know whether either Bob's or Alice's TX channel was closed, and it will not receive that information (as `None` in RX) when one of them closes the TX channel, but the other one is still open.

Comment: Sounds like you should spawn the message handling tasks, but I'm not sure what you're doing with `&mut self` there to know if that's viable or not

Comment: I solved this issue once wrapping the futures into [`async_stream`](https://docs.rs/async-stream/latest/async_stream/) and then [`futures::stream_select!`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/macro.stream_select.html) to merge them into a single flow. I don't know if it applies to your case.

Comment: Why do you use `select` if you don't want it to be cancelled? Why not use [`join`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.join.html) instead?